# ctypes-defined PROCESSENTRY32 yields incorrect size when using ctypes.sizeof

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

```
class PROCESSENTRY32(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 8
    _fields_ = [
            ("dwSize",              ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("cntUsage",            ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("th32ProcessID",       ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("th32DefaultHeapID",   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint64)),
            ("th32ModuleID",        ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("cntThreads",          ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("th32ParentProcessID", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("pcPriClassBase",      ctypes.c_long),
            ("dwFlags",             ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("szExeFile",           ctypes.c_char*MAX_PATH)
            ]
```

Here's my struct definition; some initial remarks are that with/without `_pack_=8` the structure doesn't show the correct size, nor does `_pack_=1` show the correct size. I'm basing this size issue off the fact that `Process32First` sets a `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH` error-code after called; and I see no reason in why it would be the snapshot itself.

```
def process32_first(snapshot_handle, process_entry_pointer, _ctypes_configuration=(
                    ("hSnapshot", (ctypes.c_voidp, True)),
                    ("lppe", (ctypes.POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32), True))
                   )):
    process32_first = import_winapi_function(
        "kernel32",
        "Process32First",
        argtypes_from_ctypes_configuration(_ctypes_configuration),
        ctypes.c_int
    )
    return process32_first(
        ctypes_configuration_param_select(_ctypes_configuration, 0) or snapshot_handle,
        ctypes_configuration_param_select(_ctypes_configuration, 1) or process_entry_pointer
    )
```

`ctypes_configuration_param_select` simply selects either the preset value in `_ctypes_configuration` if it isn't True or takes the user-given input. Prior to that in the `import_winapi_call` the arguments and return types are set as `ctypes.c_voidp` and `ctypes.POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32)` respectively to the WinAPI definition. The return-type is `ctypes.c_int` to represent `BOOL`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    snapshot = debug_fn(create_toolhelp32_snapshot, 0x2, 0)
    pe = PROCESSENTRY32()
    pe.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)
    debug_fn(process32_first, snapshot, ctypes.pointer(pe))
```

Here's the actual usage of the function and definition of the struct; `debug_fn` is just a wrapper that sandwiches the actual function call in between two GetLastError calls, representing the before and after error-codes.

In summary, the `debug_fn(process32_first, ...)` call yields a post-call error-code of 24/ERROR_BAD_LENGTH, and I'm chalking it up to ctypes mis-sizing the `PROCESSENTRY32`/`pe` struct.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Here's `ctypes_configuration_param_select`, `argtypes_from_ctypes_configuration`, `import_winapi_function`, `WinAPIFunction` and `debug_fn`:

```
def argtypes_from_ctypes_configuration(ctypes_configuration):
    return tuple(v[0] for _, v in ctypes_configuration)

def ctypes_configuration_param_select(ctypes_configuration, idx):
    return ctypes_configuration[idx][1][1] if ctypes_configuration[idx][1][1] is not True else False
```

`import_winapi_function` definition:

```
def import_winapi_function(namespace, name, argtypes, restype, is_unicode=UNICODE):
    gle = function_cache['kernel32.GetLastError']
    sle = function_cache['kernel32.SetLastError']
    gpa = function_cache['kernel32.GetProcAddress']
    gmh = function_cache['kernel32.GetModuleHandleA']

    name += "W" if is_unicode else "A"
    qual_fn_name = f"{namespace}.{name}"
    if qual_fn_name in function_cache:
        return function_cache[qual_fn_name]
    namespace_handle = gmh(create_string(namespace, False))
    if gle() == 127:
        sle(0)
        raise LookupError(f"Module: {namespace} doesn't exist.")
    function_handle = gpa(namespace_handle, create_string(name, False))
    if gle() != 127:
        function_cache[qual_fn_name] = WinAPIFunction(namespace, name, function_handle, restype, argtypes)
        return function_cache[qual_fn_name]
    sle(0) 
    name = name[:-1]
    qual_fn_name = qual_fn_name[:-1]
    if qual_fn_name in function_cache:
        return function_cache[qual_fn_name]
    function_handle = gpa(namespace_handle, create_string(name, False))
    if gle() == 127:
        sle(0)
        raise LookupError(f"Function: {namespace}.{name} doesn't exist.")
    function_cache[qual_fn_name] = WinAPIFunction(namespace, name, function_handle, restype, argtypes)
    return function_cache[qual_fn_name]
```

WinAPIFunction definition:

```
class WinAPIFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, module, name, handle, restype, argtypes):
        self.module = module
        self.name = name
        self.handle = handle
        self.argtypes = argtypes
        self.restype = restype 
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.module}.{self.name} @ {hex(self.handle)}>"
    __str__ = __repr__
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(self.restype, *self.argtypes)(self.handle)(*args)
```

And `debug_fn`:

```
def debug_fn(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    gle = get_last_error  # changeable
    print(f"\n{fn}:")
    print(f"\tget_last_error: {gle()}")
    res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    print(f"\tret. code: {res}")
    print(f"\tget_last_error: {gle()}\n")
    return res
```

If you want to replicate my code; then you'll just need the `function_cache` alongside the above code snippets:

```
MAX_PATH = 260
function_cache = {
        "kernel32.GetProcAddress": ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress,
        "kernel32.SetLastError": ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetLastError,
        "kernel32.GetModuleHandleA": ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA,
        "kernel32.GetLastError": ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError
        }  # primitive definitions, not WinAPIFunction instances

function_cache['kernel32.GetProcAddress'].argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_voidp,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)
)
function_cache['kernel32.GetProcAddress'].restype = ctypes.c_voidp

function_cache['kernel32.SetLastError'].argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_ulong,
)
function_cache['kernel32.SetLastError'].restype = None

function_cache['kernel32.GetModuleHandleA'].argtypes = (
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char),
)
function_cache['kernel32.GetModuleHandleA'].restype = ctypes.c_voidp

function_cache['kernel32.GetLastError'].argtypes = ()
function_cache['kernel32.GetLastError'].restype = ctypes.c_ulong
```

`UNICODE` is set to True in my environment.

Comment: Please post  **all** the code as missing parts (that ypu're trying to describe what they do) might include crucial data that you mistakenly thought it wasn't relevant. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a *mcve*. A *mcve* should contain the structure definition, the *kernel32.dll* load, `Process32First` function (and others) definition and load, arguments initialization and the call, so nothing from the last (loooong) snippet. But **most important fact is that it should work** on other people interpreter.

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how to make it shorter since my code uses a lot of internal and external function calls; with some pretty long and complex functions. Though I've edited and included everything (I believe) you would need to make the example work.

Comment: If you use the `Process32FirstW` functions you have to use wide chars (`ctypes.c_wchar` instead of `ctypes.c_char`), or better (`ctypes.wintypes.WCHAR`), so `("szExeFile", ctypes.wintypes.WCHAR * MAX_PATH)`). This is one, I'm not sure if there aren't any others.

Comment: What's different between `ctypes.c_wchar` and `ctypes.wintypes.WCHAR`?

Comment: None, the 2nd one is an alias for the 1st, but it's more *Win* friendly.

Comment: Something really strange happens on my end. Structure size doesn't change if I switch `_pack_` between ***4*** and ***8*** (it is constantly *556*), while in *C*, the same structure varies between *560* and *568* (for the same  `#pragma pack` values).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `szExeFile` member of the structure is supposed to be a `TCHAR` (or preferably a `WCHAR` as I've been told elsewhere) and not a `CHAR` as defined by the [PROCESSENTRY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-tagprocessentry32) definition and the [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types) (refer to `CHAR`) here.